# How to determine the properties of a relationship if it is not written by extension?

Tags: relations

For a given universe $U$ and a fixed subset $C$ of $U$, we define $R$ on $P(U)$ ("parts of $U$") as follows: for any $A,B⊆U$ we have ARB if and only if $A\cap C = B\cap C$

Considering that the definition of properties are:
- Reflective: $\forall x\in  aRa$ 
- Symmetrical: $\forall  a, b \in A / a R b \Rightarrow  b R a $ 
- Antisymmetric: $\forall  a, b \in A / [a R b \wedge  b R a] \Rightarrow  a = b$ 
- Transitive: $\forall  a, b, c \in A / [a R b \wedge  b R c] \Rightarrow  a R c$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of hints to get you started.

To show that $R$ is reflexive, you must show that for any $A\subseteq U$ we have $A R A$, i.e., $A\cap C=A\cap C$; is that always true?

To show that $R$ is antisymmetric, you must show that for any $A,B\subseteq U$, if $A R B$ and $B R A$, then $A=B$, i.e., if $A\cap C=B\cap C$ and $B\cap C=A\cap C$, then $A=B$. What happens if, say, $C$ is a proper subset of $U$, $A=C$, and $B=U$? Are $A\cap C$ and $B\cap C$ equal in that case? Are $A$ and $B$ equal? Can you describe a specific example of this form?

Comment: welcome back sir..! after a long time to see you in this site!

Comment: @ChinnapparajR: Thanks!